# How to get rid of a network interface?

Tags: networking, 18.04

I have this unwanted network interface that is not allowing my machine to reach the mail server that has a 172.19. IP address.

I do not know where this comes from.

How do I get permanently rid of it?

```
br-3e7279f0a872: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
    inet6 fe80::42:f8ff:fee2:4926  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:42:f8:e2:49:26  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 134  bytes 16240 (16.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
ip link set br-3e7279f0a872 down
brctl delbr br-3e7279f0a872
```

Comment: this looks like a bridge interface. What about your interface setup ? no bridge somewhere ?

Comment: found out it's a docker bridge